# Compiler warning for assignments in C# LINQ method chains?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iterator, ienumerable

I just got bit by an accidental assignment expression in a LINQ method chain.  This caused an enumerator (IEnumerable) used in a foreach loop to never enter the loop block instead of iterating through the desired collection items.  Here's a simplified example of the faulty expression used to create the iterator:

```
itemCollection.Where(theItem => theItem.status = false);
```

Obviously this is relatively easy to catch with a simple LINQ method chain like this, but in more complex cases, especially those involving multiple iterators or iterators served up by complex classes, it can be a real time waster to chase down the bug.  Is there a Visual Studio setting that flags assignments in LINQ method chains?

Comment: Simple workaround: never compare to `false` (and `true`), use `theItem => !theItem.status` (and `theItem => theItem.status`).

Comment: Does it compile? You're not providing a Func<T, bool> as you are not returning a boolean...

Comment: @LuisFilipe Assignment returns the assigned value, so the lambda *is* returning `bool`.

Comment: Another option inline with svick's is to flip the comparison: `theItem => false == theItem.Status`, but I've never gotten into that habit and it always feels backwards. I definitely prefer svick's method.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) will mark this as "Value assigned is not used in any expression".</strike> As Virtlink pointed out Resharper would not give an error in case where assignment is made to an object field. I don't think there is a VS setting, but I'm pretty sure you could write a plugin for that.

Comment: Are you sure? The value is assigned to an object field, and I doubt Resharper will warn for that. The result of the entire expression is used in the lambda expression. So, I don't have ReSharper but I suspect it will not give _that_ particular warning.